# Ways of storing inbound SMS'es

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobile, mobileconnect, sms

What ways do we have to store inbound SMS'es from clients to new Data Extension?

The limitation here is that we're trying to do this without requiring customer to specify a keyword in front of their response.

By using standard *Survey Template* in MobileConnect, we can store AMPscript to default response templates - this works perfectly fine.

To use [CreateSmsConversation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/CreateSmsConversation.htm) function, we'd need a shortcode as longcodes are not supported for this, this detail was confirmed by MC dev-support.

Any other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very little SQL Data Views available to the SMS tables - but perhaps one thing to try/test is whether the 'SMS Message Summary' report gives you the results you need. Though not ideal, if you did want to store the data in a data extension, you could then extract the report, parse the header and then import it back into a data extension I'm interested to learn if you find a solution to otherwise query the SMS data tables